# The wamp server vhosts address go to google search page

Tags: virtual-machine, hosts, wamp

my vhosts file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/"
  <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and project vhosts :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.tour.test
   DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/tour/public"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <directory "C:/wamp64/tour/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why not use the Apache 2.4 syntax like the locahost example. i.e. `Require all granted` instead of `Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all`

Comment: And `<Directory...>` with an upper case `D`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I am not misunderstanding your question, there are two possible likely culprits:

- You are forgetting to put a trailing slash at the end of your local addresses (e.g. it should http://example.test/ in the browser, not http://example.test).
- You do not have [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) set up correctly for local domains (e.g. `*.test`).

Regarding the trailing slash, this is required for local domains by current versions of Chrome, Firefox and Opera (though `localhost` shouldn't need this treatment).

Two small niggles about your ServerName/ServerAlias directives as well:

- Your `localhost` entry doesn't really need the `ServerAlias localhost` directive.
- Your `www.tour.test` host entry should (arguably) start something like:

  `ServerName tour.test` 
  `ServerAlias www.tour.test, *.tour.test`